# Is this notation ambiguous?

Tags: notation, advice

Is this notation for evaluation of integral ambiguous? 
$$\int_R f(x)\,dx=F(x)\Big\lvert_{\partial R}$$
Where $R$ is the domain of integration and $\partial R$ its boundary. I'd like to include it in a simple proof that I have to do.

EDIT:

The domains that I have to deal with in the proof are either closed intervals or $(-\infty,\infty)$. And the integration above is just the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I understood it quickly.

Comment: The goal is communication not cute notation, so I would say it depends on your audience. I understand what you are trying to do, but why burden the reader?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm still a student and as so, I think sometimes a neat (sometimes also cute) notation helps a lot with the understanding of concepts

Comment: I agree and do the same. So it depends on your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's ambiguous at all. I would say to clarify it exactly as you did whenever using it.

Answer (score 3):

I see no ambiguity.

It is pretty much *Stokes' theorem*, which is also written as
$$\int_\Omega d\omega = \oint_{\partial\Omega} \omega$$
with $\omega=F(x)$ in your case.

I think that at worst it will just be unfamiliar to people, but not ambiguous.